# Adafruit SHT31-D and Raspberry Pi2 -- Unable to read data from sensor

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, i2c, wiringpi

hopefully one of you out there can help me!

I am trying to use the [Adafruit SHT31-D](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2857) (an i2c device) board with my Pi2.  I am going off of [this datasheet](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/Humidity_and_Temperature_Sensors/Sensirion_Humidity_and_Temperature_Sensors_SHT3x_Datasheet_digital.pdf) to guide my coding efforts.  I am using Wiring Pi (wiringpi.com) to facilitate things.

I am able to successfully open a connection to the device, and sending commands seems to work fine, but I am unable to read data back!  Here is the little mini library I have put together.  I am hoping that one of you might have some experience with this sort of thing and be able to help me see where I've gone wrong.

To rule out any possible issues with the sensor hardware, I have tested it with my Arduino UNO and it works without issues.

Here is my C++ code:

**SHT3x.h**

```
#pragma once

/* Sensor Commands */
#define DEFAULT_SHT_ADDR 0x44
#define MEAS_HREP_STRETCH 0x2C06
#define MEAS_MREP_STRETCH 0x2C0D
#define MEAS_LREP_STRETCH 0x2C10
#define MEAS_HREP 0x2400
#define MEAS_MREP 0x240B
#define MEAS_LREP 0x2416

#include <cstdint>


class SHT3x {

  public:
    SHT3x(const uint8_t& i2cAddr);
    float readHumidity(const uint16_t& command) const;
    float readTempC(const uint16_t& command) const;
    float readTempF(const uint16_t& command) const;

  private:
    int8_t _fd;
    uint8_t _header;
    uint32_t getMeasurement(const uint16_t& command) const;
    void sendCommand(const uint16_t& command) const;
    uint32_t receiveData(void) const;
};
```

**SHT3x.cpp**

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
#include "SHT3x.h"


SHT3x::SHT3x(const uint8_t& i2cAddr) {
    _fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(i2cAddr);
    _header = i2cAddr << 1;
    if (_fd < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to connect");
    }
}

float SHT3x::readHumidity(const uint16_t& command) const {
    uint32_t raw_data = getMeasurement(command);
    if (!raw_data) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Bad Reading.");
    }
    uint16_t raw_humidity = raw_data & 0xFFFF;
    float humidity = 100.0 * ((float) raw_humidity / (float) 0xFFFF);
    return humidity;
}

float SHT3x::readTempC(const uint16_t& command) const {
    uint32_t raw_data = getMeasurement(command);
    if (!raw_data) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Bad Reading.");
    }
    uint16_t raw_temp = raw_data >> 16;
    float tempC = -45.0 + (175.0 * ((float) raw_temp / (float) 0xFFFF));
    return tempC;
}

float SHT3x::readTempF(const uint16_t& command) const {
    uint32_t raw_data = getMeasurement(command);
    if (!raw_data) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Bad Reading.");
    }
    uint16_t raw_temp = raw_data >> 16;
    float tempF = -49.0 + (315.0 * ((float) raw_temp / (float) 0xFFFF));
    return tempF;
}

uint32_t SHT3x::getMeasurement(const uint16_t& command) const {
    try {
        sendCommand(command);
    } catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
        throw;
    }
    return receiveData();
}

void SHT3x::sendCommand(const uint16_t& command) const {
    // break command into bytes
    uint8_t MSB = command >> 8;
    uint8_t LSB = command & 0xFF;

    // send header
    int8_t ack = wiringPiI2CWrite(_fd, _header);

    // send command
    ack &= wiringPiI2CWrite(_fd, MSB);
    ack &= wiringPiI2CWrite(_fd, LSB);

    // handle errors
    if (ack) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Sending command failed.");
    }
}

uint32_t SHT3x::receiveData(void) const {
    uint32_t data;

    // send header
    uint8_t read_header = _header | 0x01;
    int8_t ack = wiringPiI2CWrite(_fd, read_header);

    // handle errors
    if (ack) throw std::runtime_error("Unable to read data.");

    // read data
    data = wiringPiI2CRead(_fd);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("Data: %d\n", data);
        data <<= 8;
        if (i != 1) {
            data |= wiringPiI2CRead(_fd);
        } else {
            wiringPiI2CRead(_fd);   // skip checksum
        }
    }
    wiringPiI2CRead(_fd);   // second checksum
    return data;
}
```

Comment: What is your code doing to indicate that it failed to read?  e.g. does it throw a runtime error "Unable to read data.", or throw "Bad Reading.", or something else?

Comment: @MattJordan: It is throwing "Bad Reading."  I am always just getting a zeroed out value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SHT31 uses 16bit read and write, rather than using 2 8bit writes you might be better off using wiringpi's 16bit write. wiringPiI2CWriteReg16(). Same thing applies to the read.

Below is a very early copy of what I've done to read the sht31-d on a PI. It has no dependencies except i2c-dev.   Heater enable/disable is not working, but softreset, clearstatus, getserial & get temp/humid are all fine.

```
/*
 * Referances
 * https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface
 * https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SHT31
 * https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/Humidity_and_Temperature_Sensors/Sensirion_Humidity_and_Temperature_Sensors_SHT3x_Datasheet_digital.pdf
 *
 * This depends on i2c dev lib
 * sudo apt-get install libi2c-dev
 *
 * Below is also a good one to have, but be careful i2cdump from the below cause the sht31 interface to become unstable for me
 * and requires a hard-reset to recover correctly.
 * sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
 *
 * on PI make sure below 2 commands are in /boot/config.txt
 * dtparam=i2c_arm=on
 * dtparam=i2c1_baudrate=10000
 * I know we are slowing down the baurate from optimal, but it seems to be the most stable setting in my testing.
 * add another 0 to the above baudrate for max setting, ie dtparam=i2c1_baudrate=100000
 */

#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SHT31_INTERFACE_ADDR       1
#define SHT31_DEFAULT_ADDR         0x44
#define SHT31_READ_SERIALNO        0x3780
#define SHT31_MEAS_HIGHREP_STRETCH 0x2C06 // Doesn't work on PI
#define SHT31_MEAS_MEDREP_STRETCH  0x2C0D // Seems to work on PI but shouldn't
#define SHT31_MEAS_LOWREP_STRETCH  0x2C10 // Seems to work on PI but shouldn't
#define SHT31_MEAS_HIGHREP         0x2400 // Doesn't work on PI
#define SHT31_MEAS_MEDREP          0x240B
#define SHT31_MEAS_LOWREP          0x2416
#define SHT31_READSTATUS           0xF32D
#define SHT31_CLEARSTATUS          0x3041
#define SHT31_SOFTRESET            0x30A2
#define SHT31_HEATER_ENABLE        0x306D
#define SHT31_HEATER_DISABLE       0x3066

#define CHECK_BIT(var,pos) (((var)>>(pos)) & 1)

/*
 * delay:
 *  Wait for some number of milliseconds
 *********************************************************************************
 */

void delay (unsigned int howLong)
{
  struct timespec sleeper, dummy ;

  sleeper.tv_sec  = (time_t)(howLong / 1000) ;
  sleeper.tv_nsec = (long)(howLong % 1000) * 1000000 ;

  nanosleep (&sleeper, &dummy) ;
}

/*
*
* CRC-8 formula from page 14 of SHT spec pdf
*
* Test data 0xBE, 0xEF should yield 0x92
*
* Initialization data 0xFF
* Polynomial 0x31 (x8 + x5 +x4 +1)
* Final XOR 0x00
*/
uint8_t crc8(const uint8_t *data, int len)
{
  const uint8_t POLYNOMIAL = 0x31;
  uint8_t crc = 0xFF;
  int j;
  int i;

  for (j = len; j; --j ) {
    crc ^= *data++;

    for ( i = 8; i; --i ) {
      crc = ( crc & 0x80 )
            ? (crc << 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL
            : (crc << 1);
    }
  }
  return crc;
}


/*
 * 
 * buffer should return with data read, size defined by readsize
 *********************************************************************************
*/

int writeandread(int fd, uint16_t sndword, uint8_t *buffer, int readsize)
{
  int rtn;
  uint8_t snd[3];
  // Split the 16bit word into two 8 bits that are flipped.
  snd[0]=(sndword >> 8) & 0xff;
  snd[1]=sndword & 0xff;

  rtn = write(fd, snd, 2);
  if ( rtn != 2 ) {
    return 1;
  } 

  if (readsize > 0) {
    delay(10);
    rtn = read(fd, buffer, readsize);
    if ( rtn < readsize) {
      return 2;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

void printserialnum(int file)
{
  uint8_t buf[10];
  int rtn;

  rtn = writeandread(file, SHT31_READ_SERIALNO, buf, 6);
  if (rtn != 0)
    printf("ERROR:- Get serial i2c %s failed\n",(rtn==1?"write":"read"));
  else {
    if (buf[2] != crc8(buf, 2) || buf[5] != crc8(buf+3, 2))
      printf("WARNING:- Get serial CRC check failed, don't trust result\n");

    uint32_t serialNo = ((uint32_t)buf[0] << 24)
    | ((uint32_t)buf[1] << 16)
    | ((uint32_t)buf[3] << 8)
    | (uint32_t)buf[4];
    printf("Serial# = %d\n",serialNo);
  }
}

void printtempandhumidity(int file)
{
  uint8_t buf[10];
  int rtn;

    rtn = writeandread(file, SHT31_MEAS_MEDREP_STRETCH, buf, 6);

  if (rtn != 0)
    printf("ERROR:- Get temp/humidity i2c %s failed\n",(rtn==1?"write":"read"));
  else {
    if ( buf[2] != crc8(buf, 2) || buf[5] != crc8(buf+3, 2))
      printf("WARNING:- Get temp/humidity CRC check failed, don't trust results\n");

    uint16_t ST, SRH;
    ST = buf[0];
    ST <<= 8;
    ST |= buf[1];

    SRH = buf[3];
    SRH <<= 8;
    SRH |= buf[4];

    double stemp = ST;
    stemp *= 175;
    stemp /= 0xffff;
    stemp = -45 + stemp;

    double stempf = ST;
    stempf *= 315;
    stempf /= 0xffff;
    stempf = -49 + stempf;

    printf("Temperature %.2fc - %.2ff\n",stemp,stempf);

    double shum = SRH;
    shum *= 100;
    shum /= 0xFFFF;

    printf("Humidity %.2f%%\n",shum);
  }
}

void printBitStatus(uint16_t stat)
{
  printf("Status\n");
  printf("    Checksum status %d\n", CHECK_BIT(stat,0));
  printf("    Last command status %d\n", CHECK_BIT(stat,1));
  printf("    Reset detected status %d\n", CHECK_BIT(stat,4));
  printf("    'T' tracking alert %d\n", CHECK_BIT(stat,10));
  printf("    'RH' tracking alert %d\n", CHECK_BIT(stat,11));
  printf("    Heater status %d\n", CHECK_BIT(stat,13));
  printf("    Alert pending status %d\n", CHECK_BIT(stat,15));
}

void printstatus(int file)
{
  uint8_t buf[10];
  int rtn;

  rtn = writeandread(file, SHT31_READSTATUS, buf, 3);
  if (rtn != 0)
    printf("ERROR:- readstatus %s failed\n",(rtn==1?"write":"read"));
  else {
    if ( buf[2] != crc8(buf, 2))
      printf("WARNING:- Get status CRC check failed, don't trust results\n");

    uint16_t stat = buf[0];
    stat <<= 8;
    stat |= buf[1];  
    printBitStatus(stat);
  }
}



void clearstatus(int file)
{
  if( writeandread(file, SHT31_CLEARSTATUS, NULL, 0) != 0)
    printf("ERROR:- sht31 clear status failed\n");
  else 
    printf("Clearing status - ok\n");
}

void softreset(int file)
{
  if( writeandread(file, SHT31_SOFTRESET, NULL, 0) != 0)
    printf("ERROR:- sht31 soft reset failed\n");
  else  
    printf("Soft reset - ok\n");
}

void enableheater(int file)
{
  if( writeandread(file, SHT31_HEATER_ENABLE, NULL, 0) != 0)
    printf("ERROR:- sht31 heater enable failed\n");
  else 
    printf("Enabiling heater - ok\n");
}

void disableheater(int file)
{
  if( writeandread(file, SHT31_HEATER_DISABLE, NULL, 0) != 0)
    printf("ERROR:- sht31 heater enable failed\n");
  else  
    printf("Disableing heater - ok\n");
}

int main()
{

  int file;
  char filename[20];

  snprintf(filename, 19, "/dev/i2c-%d", SHT31_INTERFACE_ADDR);
  file = open(filename, O_RDWR);
  if (file < 0) {
    printf("ERROR:- Can't open %s\n",filename);
    exit(1);
  }

  if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, SHT31_DEFAULT_ADDR) < 0) {
    printf("ERROR:- Connecting to sht31 I2C address 0x%02hhx\n", SHT31_DEFAULT_ADDR);
    exit(1);
  }

  softreset(file);
  printtempandhumidity(file);
  printstatus(file);

  close(file);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I will be studying this and the i2c spec so that I can understand this better.